What is "ReverseDirectorystore.Shadow 3" that I found it on my desktop of MacBook Air2017 running Monterey?
I was recently scanning through my MacBook Air 13 in 2017 running Monterey when I noticed a few programs installed on my desktop that I'd never seen before. One was particularly troubling just based on the nefarious-sounding name of ReverseDirectorystore.Shadow 3.
I don't recall installing this program along with quite others. My Apple ID is also used on a MacBook I gave to my girlfriend so she has access to my Apple ID but I am not sure if she can/would upload programs to my laptop. Can anyone please shed some light on this situation for us?

When you say on your desktop, what is the exact path where you find each file you are curious about?

I would not recommend sharing the same AppleID between two people (except for Family setup, where there are "sub-IDs". You are likely to end up with a massive mess of each other's data, which may be difficult to untie...

reverseDirectoryStore.shadow is not a program. It is a data file that is part of the Spotlight index, which allows you to search for your files using Spotlight and Finder. It is a normal part of any macOS installation.
